# How to set keyup on whole page in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to set a `v-on:keyup.enter` on the whole page, not only for an input element in javascript framework Vue.js ?

Answer (score 26):

Perhaps a better way to do this is with a Vue component. This would allow you to control when you listen to events by including or not including the component. Then you could attach event listeners to [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/) using the [no-ssr component](https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-no-ssr).

Here is how you create the component:

```html
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>
  
<script>
  export default {
    created() {
      const component = this;
      this.handler = function (e) {
        component.$emit('keyup', e);
      }
      window.addEventListener('keyup', this.handler);
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
      window.removeEventListener('keyup', this.handler);
    }
  }
</script>
  
<style lang="stylus" scoped>
  div {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

Then on the page you want to use that component you'd add this HTML:

```html
<keyboard-events v-on:keyup="keyboardEvent"></keyboard-events>
```

And then you'll have to add your event handler method:

```js
methods: {
  keyboardEvent (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
      // run your code
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Short answer is yes, but how depends on your context. If you are using vue-router as I am on a current project, you would want to add to the outer-most element you want that applied to. In my case I'm using the actual app.vue entry point's initial div element.

There is one catch that I believe is a hard requirement, the element has to be within the potentially focusable elements. The way I'm dealing with that is setting a -1 tabindex and just declaring my super-hotkeys (mostly for debug purposes right now) on the parent element in my app.

```
<template>
  <div
    id="app-main"
    tabindex="-1"
    @keyup.enter="doSomething"
  >
    <everything-else></everything-else>
  </div>
</template>
```

---

**EDIT:**

As a side note, I also added a touch of additional configuration to my vue-router to make sure the right element is focused when I transition pages. This allows the pageup/pagedown scrolling to already be in the right section based on the content area being the only scrollable section. You'd also have to add the tabindex="-1" to the app-content element as well.

```
router.afterEach(function (transition) {
  document.getElementById('app-content').focus();
});
```

and the basis of my app-content component:

```
<template>
  <div id="app-content" tabindex="-1">
    <router-view
      id="app-view"
      transition="app-view__transition"
      transition-mode="out-in"
    ></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This answer seems to get a fair number of views and still should be fairly relevant, but take a look at the following link if you want fully fully global window based hotkeys (about half way down): https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/01/vue-js-cant-help-head-body/

Answer (score 7):

I created a small npm module that takes care of global keypress events in Vue, hope it makes someone's life easier:
https://github.com/lupas/vue-keypress

Answer (score 5):

My simplest approach:

Add into your root Vue component (or any other component):

```
new Vue({
    //...
    created() {
        window.addEventListener('keypress', this.onKeyPress);
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        window.removeEventListener('keypress', this.onKeyPress);
    },
    methods: {
        onKeyPress(e) {
            console.log('KEYPRESS EVENT', e)
            //... your code
        }
    }
    //...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In Vue 3 composition API, you can do it with a [composable](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html):

```
import { onMounted, onUnmounted } from "vue";

export function useKeyupEvent(handler) {
  onMounted(() => document.addEventListener("keyup", handler));
  onUnmounted(() => document.removeEventListener("keyup", handler));
}
```

and then in your component setup:

```
useKeyupEvent( event => console.log(event))
```