# Vue JS @keyup.ecs doesn' t work in components template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

I using twig template engine and vue js. I have modals and open and close methods. Open methods working if clicking but close methods doesn' t work then press "esc" key. İf I use @keyup.esc="closeModal" in twig template its work. But its doesn't work my components templates .

> in javascript

```
 template : `
      <div class="row masonry-layout isotope_container">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 isotope-item" v-for="item in materials">
          <div class="vertical-item content-padding topmargin_80">
            <div class="item-media">
              <img v-bind:src="item.image" alt="">
              <div class="media-links p-link">
                <div class="links-wrap">
                  <i class="flaticon-arrows-2"></i>
                </div>
                <a v-if="isNews" @click="openModal(item)" v-on:keyup.esc="closeModal()" class="abs-link"></a>
                <a v-if="!isNews" v-bind:href="item.image" class="abs-link"></a>
              </div>
            </div>
              ...
```

> in twig

```
  <div id="cart" class="container">

    <cart
    v-bind:materials="news"
    type="news">
  </cart>

  <modal ></modal>
</div>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: `keyup` would only works if you are focusing on the element where this event listener is added on.

Comment: Thanks, What should I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422076/how-to-set-keyup-on-whole-page-in-vue-js