# vue keydown even only firing when elements are active

Tags: javascript, vue.js, keydown

I'm running into an odd snag when trying to listen for keydown events in vuejs.

I have a keydown event attached to a div tag that encloses my entire visible area:

```
<template>
    <div class="layout-wrapper" @keydown="handleKeyDown"> // <--- our keydown event
        <div class="workspace">
            <animation-canvas class="animation-canvas"></animation-canvas>
            <control-panel class="control-panel"></control-panel>
        </div>
        <dock class="dock"></dock>
    </div>
</template>
```

When they event fires, I'm handling it with a method that logs to the console and then switches based on the key pressed:

```
    handleKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        console.log('down');
        switch (event.key) {
            case 'ArrowLeft':
                alert('left');
                break;
            case 'ArrowRight':
                alert('right');
                break;
        }
```

At first I thought the event wasn't firing or the listener wasn't attaching correctly, but then I found that the keydown listener only fires when I press the keydown with an input element active.

[image]

What am I missing here? It's been a while since I've done front end work, but I was pretty sure they keydown event didn't require an input event selected (right?)

Comment: Events are bound to an element and JS is propagating events by default. This means that your keydown event will be triggered only if the event is performed on the element itself or one of its children. Then, if you want your event to be global, it should be set on a global element such as the `<body>` element. Here is a small example to showcase this: 
https://jsfiddle.net/8v2tra6q/

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53600988/8211893

Comment: The two approaches I've used (depending on the UX requirements) are either: (1) create a global listener (make sure to remove it after the component is removed), (2) focus the element you need to listen to (e.g. on page load + mouse enter, etc.).

Comment: Ah, god I was so caught up in scoping everything to the components that I completely forgot about attaching/detaching at a global level :P Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I got so hung up on scoping all logic to the component's elements that I didn't think to attach the listener at a global level (thanks for the suggestions in the comments).

I updated my component with the following lifecycle methods:

```
 mounted() {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);
    },

    beforeDestroy() {
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);
    },
```

and now it triggers everywhere so I'm all good. Thanks for the help!